# Перечисление атрибутов модуля

Tags: python

Я импортировал модуль ccxt, в нем есть множество атрибутов.
Обычно я работаю с каждым по отдельности, например:

```
finance = ccxt.finance({params...})

exchange = ccxt.exchange({params...})

asset= ccxt.asset({params...})
```

Далее, я использую по очереди мои функции finance, exchange, asset и так далее.

Теперь мне нужно записать ccxt единожды, а все нужные атрибуты я вывел отдельно, и хочу использовать цикл, чтобы подставить их после ccxt.

```
my_atributes = ['finance','exchange', 'asset']
for i in my_atributes:
    ccxt.i({params...})
```

Такая запись не работает, потому что нельзя использовать строки в качестве атрибута для ccxt. Если записать элемента списка без кавычек, то они станут функциями, и код выдаст ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
names = ['finance', 'exchange', 'asset']
for name in names:
    getattr(ccxt, name)({params...})
```

либо

```py
funcs = [ccxt.finance, ccxt.exchange, ccxt.asset]
for f in funcs:
    f({params...})
```